# Как вычислить среднее для группы строчек по определенному условию?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Есть большой набор данных (300МБ). Приведу несколько строчек из этого набора:

```
id;OUTPUT;Year;Doy;Seconds;X[m];Y[m];Z[m];latitude[degrees];longitude[degrees];height[m]
0;OUTPUT;2010;186;210,00;1592131,3251;4808652,6133;3866691,8573;37,542287690;71,680438306;2306,2186
1;OUTPUT;2010;186;240,00;1592131,4656;4808652,5344;3866692,7141;37,542293977;71,680436517;2306,7163
2;OUTPUT;2010;186;270,00;1592131,4211;4808652,1813;3866692,7649;37,542296257;71,680435738;2306,4704
3;OUTPUT;2010;186;300,00;1592131,2261;4808652,5151;3866691,9115;37,542288759;71,680439020;2306,1530
4;OUTPUT;2010;186;330,00;1592130,9351;4808652,8012;3866690,8864;37,542280449;71,680443161;2305,6712
5;OUTPUT;2010;186;360,00;1592130,9608;4808652,4677;3866690,2105;37,542277316;71,680441700;2305,0146
```

Из этого набора данных хочу получить средние значения по нескольким строчкам (не по всем значениям). Задумка такая: поделить каждое значение столбца `Seconds` на 3600 (чтобы секунды в часы перевести), и если деление без остатка, то  вычислить среднее для `X[m], Y[m], Z[m]` от начала таблицы до вот этого условия.

Не получается это реализовать. Посоветуйте, как можно такое сделаать?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__

Comment: В наборе данных данных приведены координаты, через каждые 30 секунд. Нужно получить средние значения этих координат, для каждого часа, т.е. для вычислить средние значения координат для каждых 3600 секунд.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

```
res = df.assign(hr=df["Seconds"] // 3600).groupby("hr").mean()
```

результат для примера данных из вопроса:

```
In [48]: res
Out[48]:
      id    Year    Doy  Seconds          X[m]          Y[m]          Z[m]  latitude[degrees]  longitude[degrees]    height[m]
hr
0.0  2.5  2010.0  186.0    285.0  1.592131e+06  4.808653e+06  3.866692e+06          37.542287           71.680439  2306.040683
```